# TWRP not asking me to enter password to decrypt

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, twrp, encryption

I need to restore from a backup. However TWRP stopped asking me for the password to decrypt. In the terminal emulator I tried `twrp decrypt 1234` but got the error "Failed to decrypt data". Whenever I try to use any other feature in TWRP, such as restore, it says "Failed to decrypt data".  and "extracTarFork() process ended with ERROR: 255"

How can I restore from a backup?

Comment: @beeshyams no it isn't a multi user backup. It's TWRP 3-3-10, is there a new version for Xperia XZ1 Compact?

Comment: @beeshyams as far as I could determine, no there isn't a newer version for XZ1 Compact. By trying things out I got it to work (see answer bellow). I'm curious, is this a known bug? Why is it sometimes TWRP just doesn't ask for password?

Comment: TWRP needs a working firmware for decryption. if system vendor or modem is wiped, the workaround is to format userdata in order to remove encryption completely, so TWRP can mount it unencrypted

Comment: @alecxs all I did was flash Lineage 17 so how could that corrupt the firmware?

Comment: just a guess as you stated you wiped everything. encryption also depends on android version - switching between ROMs can also cause this

Comment: If switching between ROMs can cause this how does one backup their phone before trying a new one? I thought this was one of the  main use cases of TWRP. @alecxs

Comment: backup data + internal storage -> to external storage like MicroSD Card, USB-OTG or *adb pull /sdcard*

Comment: for switching between ROMs i recommend Migrate

Answer (score 3):

Copied from comments:

> TWRP needs a working firmware for decryption. If system vendor or
> modem is wiped, the workaround is to format userdata in order to
> remove encryption completely, so TWRP can mount it unencrypted.

Through experimenting I was able to get it to work by doing the following. First, try reflashing just TWRP in fastboot mode: `fastboot flash recovery twrp.img`. This may be enough, but if not se bellow . My phone is an Xperia so replace steps 1. and 2. with however you normally would install firmware.

**Steps:**

1. download phone's Firmware as ftf
2. Use flashtool to flash firmware
3. Use fastboot to flash TWRP
4. Use TWRP to wipe all data, but make sure not to wipe the backup you're trying to restore!
5. Use TWRP to install a new ROM.
6. Setup new ROM e.g. sign into WiFi
7. Reboot to TWRP again
8. Now TWRP should ask for password and you will be able to decrypt